# Direction of outward normal differential $\hat n\ ds$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, plane-curves

In vector calculus, why is the outward normal differential $\hat n\ ds$ around a closed curve $dy\ \hat i - dx\ \hat j$?  Why isn't it $-dy\ \hat i + dx\ \hat j$ or something else?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?